# modifying default tabular behaviour

Tags: tables, macros, rules, programming, booktabs

I basically do all my tables the same way:

[image]

Is it possible to make tabular automate the `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` and `\hdashline`s?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,arydshln}

\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[htp]
    \begin{center}
      \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}

          \toprule
          First & Second & Third \\
          \midrule
          AAAAA & BBBBB  & CCCCC \\ \hdashline
          DDDDD & EEEEE  & FFFFF \\ \hdashline
          GGGGG & HHHHH  & IIIII \\ \hdashline
          JJJJJ & KKKKK  & LLLLL \\ %hdashline
          \bottomrule

        \end{tabular}}
      %makebox
    \end{center}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably a better idea to make a template for it in your editor rather than trying to change existing code

Answer (score 1):

This is more a remark. You can achieve something of that sort with a Ti*k*Z matrix, using the undocumented `execute at end matrix` key. This is because a Ti*k*Z matrix "knows" how many rows and columns it has. Here is a very basic version that illustrates the point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{tjt263 tabular/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
execute at end matrix={
\draw[very thick] (\tikzmatrixname.north west) -- (\tikzmatrixname.north east)
(\tikzmatrixname.south west) -- (\tikzmatrixname.south east);
\foreach \YY in {2,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow} 
{\path (\tikzmatrixname-\the\numexpr\YY-1\relax-1) -- (\tikzmatrixname-\YY-1) 
coordinate[midway] (aux-\YY);
\ifnum\YY=2
\draw (\tikzmatrixname.west|-aux-\YY) -- (\tikzmatrixname.east|-aux-\YY);
\else
\draw[dotted] (\tikzmatrixname.west|-aux-\YY) -- (\tikzmatrixname.east|-aux-\YY);
\fi}
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[tjt263 tabular]{
 First & Second & Third \\
 AAAAA & BBBBB  & CCCCC \\ 
 DDDDD & EEEEE  & FFFFF \\ 
 GGGGG & HHHHH  & IIIII \\ 
 JJJJJ & KKKKK  & LLLLL \\ 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works for the example of your MWE, but may not work for much more complex examples. There are things that can be added very easily such as the extension to matrices in which the cell contents have different heights. What is much harder to achieve (and not done to the best of my knowledge) is support of `l` or `r` type columns. This might be doable with some `eqparbox`-type trickery but to the best of my knowledge this has not yet been spelled out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the powerful methods of `expl3`.

The body is split at `\\`, then the header row is separated off; we just need to take care about a trailing `\\`, that would produce an empty row, so we check that (see comments in the code).

The `tjttabular` environment has an optional argument, default 3; if you type `\begin{tjttabular}[4]`, you'll get a four column table.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,arydshln,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{tjttabular}{O{3} +b}
 {
  \tjt_tabular:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l__tjt_tabular_body_seq
\tl_new:N \l__tjt_tabular_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l__tjt_tabular_last_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tjt_tabular:nn
 {
  % split the body at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tjt_tabular_body_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  % pop the first item (the headers)
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tjt_tabular_body_seq \l__tjt_tabular_first_tl
  % pop the last item (possibly empty, if \\ is used in the last line)
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__tjt_tabular_body_seq \l__tjt_tabular_last_tl
  % if the last item is not empty, put it back
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__tjt_tabular_last_tl
   {
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__tjt_tabular_body_seq \l__tjt_tabular_last_tl
   }
  % now typeset the table, separate items by \\\hdashline
  \begin{tabular}{*{#1}{c}}
  \toprule
  \l__tjt_tabular_first_tl \\
  \midrule
  \seq_use:Nn \l__tjt_tabular_body_seq { \\ \hdashline } \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tjttabular}
  First & Second & Third \\

  AAAAA & BBBBB  & CCCCC \\
  DDDDD & EEEEE  & FFFFF \\
  GGGGG & HHHHH  & IIIII \\
  JJJJJ & KKKKK  & LLLLL \\
\end{tjttabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\begin{center}` should not be used inside `table`, because it adds unwanted space; `\centering` is the correct command to use.

Also `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{...}` does nothing, as `\centering` already takes care of the centering business.